# On the eigen vectors of a diagonalizable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory, eigenvector

Let us consider the space $M_n(\mathbb{C})$. By a unitary matrix $U=(u_{ij})$ we mean that $U^{-1}=(\overline{u_{ji}})$.

> Q. Let $U$ be a unitary matrix. I am looking for the pairs of matrices $(D,A)$ satisfying the following conditions: (1) $D$ is a diagonal matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, (2) $UAU^{-1}=D$, (3) $U$ and $A$ have the same eigen-vectors. In general case, does  there exist such a pair? How can we find a formula to produce all such of the pairs?

Comment: $U = A = D$?...

Comment: $D$ should be a diagonal matrix not diagonalizable.

Comment: [Indeed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420993/on-the-eigen-vectors-of-a-diagonalizable-matrix/420994#comment1081451_420993); my [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420993/on-the-eigen-vectors-of-a-diagonalizable-matrix/420994#comment1081449_420993) was suggesting a unitary matrix $U$ and a diagonalisable matrix $A$ both of which are already diagonal as an obvious, silly example.  My [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/420994) says that in fact this is (essentially; we don't actually need $U = A$) the only example.

Comment: $A$ is diagonalizable, so if $U,A$ have the same eigenvectors, then they commute, so $A=D$, and $U$ is any diagonal unitary matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [mentioned](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420993/on-the-eigen-vectors-of-a-diagonalizable-matrix#comment1081449_420993) the silly example $U = A = D$ offhand, but, in fact, it's essentially the only example.  In general, note that the columns of $U^{-1}$ are the eigenvectors of $A$.  So we're asking for, at least, a unitary matrix $U$ that admits the columns of $U^{-1}$ as eigenvectors.  But $U U^{-1} = I$, so this means that $U$ must be diagonal.